# Sum of the series$\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1.4}{5.10}+\frac{1.4.7}{5.10.15}-.... $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1.4}{5.10}+\frac{1.4.7}{5.10.15}-.... $

My attempt:

$\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1.4}{5.10}+\frac{1.4.7}{5.10.15}-.... $
$=\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1.4}{5^2 1.2}+\frac{1.4.7}{5^3.1.2.3}-.... $

Then wanted to use the series expansion of $e^x$. But could not proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking at the series

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n-2)!_3}{n!}x^n$$

with the particular solution given by $-S(-1/5)$. Let $R(x)=S(x^3)$. Now notice that

$$\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}xR(x)=\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n-2)!_3}{n!}x^{3n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n+1)!_3}{n!}x^{3n}$$

But on the other hand,

$$\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}R(x)=\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n-2)!_3}{n!}x^{3n}=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n-2)!_3}{(n-1)!}x^{3n-1}=3x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3n+1)!_3}{n!}x^{3n}$$

Hence we have

$$\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}R(x)=3x^2+3x^2\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}xR(x)$$

Expanding out with product rule:

$$R'(x)=3x^2+3x^2R(x)+3x^3R'(x)$$

Rearranging gives us

$$(1-3x^3)R'(x)=(3x^2+1)R(x)$$

which is separable. Solving with $R(0)=0$ and we get

$$R(x)=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{1-3x^3}}-1$$

and hence

$$S(x)=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{1-3x}}-1$$

with the particular solution given by

$$-S\left(-\frac15\right)=1-\frac{\sqrt[3]5}2$$

Answer (score 1):

A slight different approach
$$
\eqalign{
  & S = {1 \over 5} - {{1 \cdot 4} \over {5 \cdot 10}} + {{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7} \over {5 \cdot 10 \cdot 15}} -  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 5}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1 + 3k} \right)} } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}\left( { - {1 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 5}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{3^{\,n + 1} \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1/3 + k} \right)} } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}\left( { - {1 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {3 \over 5}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\left( {1/3} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n + 1\,} } } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}\left( { - {3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n} }  = {3 \over 5}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\left( {n + 1/3} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n + 1\,} } } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}\left( { - {3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n + 1/3 \cr 
  n + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( { - {3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n + 1} }  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n + 1/3 \cr 
  n + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( {{3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n + 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
   - 1/3 \cr 
  n + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( {{3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n + 1} }  =  - \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
   - 1/3 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)\left( {{3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
   - 1/3 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)\left( {{3 \over 5}} \right)^{\,n} }  = 1 - \left( {1 + {3 \over 5}} \right)^{ - 1/3}  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 - \root 3 \of {{5 \over 8}}  = 1 - {{\root 3 \of 5 } \over 2} \cr} 
$$
where $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } ,\quad x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } $ represent respectively the [Falling and Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)